# Annihilator of minimal prime ideal in a commutative Noetherian ring

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $M$ be an $R$-module of finite length and $N$ a maximal submodule of $M.$

> Is there an element $m$ in $M$ such that $m(N:M)=0$?

It is a generalization of this result:

In a Notherian ring $R,$ all minimal prime ideals have non-zero annihilator.

Comment: What do you mean by m(N:M)=0?

Comment: @FanZheng:  Presumably $(N:M)\subset R$ is the annihilator of $M/N$ and the OP is treating $R$ as acting on the right..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put $P=(N:M)$.

Because $N$ is a maximal submodule, $P$ is a maximal ideal.

Because $M$ has finite length, there is some minimal $k$ such that $MP^k=MP^{k+1}$.   By Nakayama, there exists $s\in 1+P$ such that $MsP^k=0$.

Put $T=MsP^{k-1}$.  If $T=0$, then $MP^{k-1}\subset MP^k$, contradicting minimality of $k$.  So $T\neq 0$.  But by the preceding paragraph, $TP=0$.

So if $k\neq 0$, then any nonzero $m\in T$ will do.  But if $k=0$, then $Ms=0$. Therefore $s\in ann(M)\subseteq (N:M)=P$ and hence $1\in P$, a contradiction.